# Points for a quarter-circle outline

Tags: python, rotation, line, geometry, tkinter-canvas

My problem today is, that I wan't to animate a stick, which falls over. so first the stick stands:
|
and then it falls to the right:
/
_
But how do I get that animation using Pythons Canvas?
Canvas doesn't have a function to rotate items, so I need a mathematical formula like
x = y*z
My script to now:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.resizable(0,0)
canv = Canvas(root)
canv.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
line = canv.create_line(1,400,1,0,fill="#000000")

def test():
    y = 1
    for i in range(1,401):
        sleep(0.005)
        x= i
        y= 400 - sqrt(400**2 - x**2)      ###### Problem already solved :)
        canv.coords(line, 0, 400, x, y)
        root.update()

test()
```

So the stick should go like this:
[image]

As you can see above in the script, my problem is already solved :)

Comment: Why not post your solution as an answer, so you can mark and close the question, or consider marking the answer you got as accepted if it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of your stick is 400, and the x position of the end not at the origin is i, then by Pythagoras' theorem, the y position is simply sqrt(400^2 - i^2) - or am I missing the point? (Pun not intended.)

Comment: 2 coords. one (stay): (0,0) the other (x,y) I need to find that. so length is 400, the staying point is 0,0 and I need to get the points on the way of the other one, so that it's way would look like a quarter-circle with the radius of 400 and the middle at 0,0.

Comment: Then yes, the coordinates of the moving end would be (x, sqrt(400^2 - x^2)).

Comment: No. What I have now, is looking awesome, but not what I need. There's a graphic now up there, which displays what I need. Your option makes a line, which starts from 0,0 and ends on 400,400. The way looks awesome, but i need something from 0,400 to 400,0

Comment: Are you sure you've entered it correctly?
x = 0 -> y = sqrt(400^2-x^2) = sqrt(400^2) = 400;
x = 400 -> y = sqrt(400^2-x^2) = sqrt(0) = 0

Those are the conditions, no?
The plot is a quarter circle (in the regime you're interested in): [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+sqrt(400^2-x^2))

Comment: Wait. Possibly it's what I need - but inverted. You know - I guess it's the right animation, but with wrong points. I think at this moment I'm to stupid or tired or whatever, to get it to the right points. Could you please help me again? Yours goes from 0,0 to 400,400 so we need to move one 400 to one nill 0,0(0,400) and 400,0(400,400). Please help me solving that little problem in my brain :D

Comment: Of course. I know the problem. My thinking mistake. y400 is at the buttom, not at the top. So I've got to calculate 400 - sqrt(400^2-x^2) I guess - Let's see.